# Search text using text with parenthesis as parameter in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a text file and I'm trying to read that text file and  find all texts matching my regex expression. 
It works well when its parameters are without parenthesis.

This works:

```
 from_str = "this is a text"
```

And when the text contains parenthesis it doesn't work.

```
from_str = "this is a text with (parenthesis)"
```

Here's my full code:

```
 from_str = "this is a text with (parenthesis)"
 str_to_text = "Freddie Mac Form"
 text = File.open(texturl).read
 text = text.scan(/#{from_str}(.*?)#{str_to_text}/m)[0]
 abort text.to_s    # Returning no data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape your variables with [`Regexp.escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-escape).

```
from_str = "this is a text with (parenthesis)"
str_to_text = "Freddie Mac Form"
text = File.open(texturl).read
text = text.scan(/#{Regexp.escape(from_str)}(.*?)#{Regexp.escapestr_to_text)}/m)[0]
abort text.to_s    # Returning data
```

Comment: Wow thats excellent, it works now. Can you please elaborate why mine was not working?

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html):

`The following are metacharacters (, ), [, ], {, }, ., ?, +, *. They have a specific meaning when appearing in a pattern. To match them literally they must be backslash-escaped. To match a backslash literally backslash-escape that: \.`

Comment: You mean Regexp.escape add backslash to any metacharacters found in the text.

Comment: I'm sure it converts it into '"this is a text with \\(parenthesis\\)"'. It's here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-escape